# Convert sql to ActiveRecord scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following sql:

```
select * from slide_results where tags @> ARRAY['pro']::varchar[]
```

I converted it to ActiveRecord scope:

```
scope :by_tags, ->(tags) { where('tags @> ?', "{ARRAY[pro]::varchar[]}") }
```

but unfortunately it does not return the same results?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have your `ARRAY[...]` and cast in the wrong place and you have some stray braces; also, the type cast shouldn't be necessary. You should say:

```
where('tags @> array[?]', 'pro')
```

Otherwise, ActiveRecord will see `{ARRAY[pro]::varchar[]}` as a single string that should be escaped and wrapped in singles quotes yielding:

```
tags @> '{ARRAY[pro]::varchar[]}'
```

which doesn't do what you want as `'{ARRAY[pro]::varchar[]}'` is just an SQL string literal.

If the array's content is always just `'pro'` then you could go straight to:

```
where("tags @> array['pro']")
```

as the placeholder isn't really necessary.